# Downloading file with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web, firefox, automation

I am trying to automate a workflow using python and selenium where i will open a page and download couple of .txt file.

My web driver initialization looks like below:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "c:\\selenium_firefox_downloads\\")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

The above code is working fine, but the problem is there are some files whose extension are in uppercase. For e.g. file.TXT, the above code is not working for this particular case.

Whenever i am trying to download files with .TXT extension instead of saving it to directory `c:\selenium_firefox_downloads\` firefox is giving me a popup window and asking me where to save it.

I am not sure if the MIME type 'text/plain' is compatible only .txt (i.e. in lowercase)

Could anyone please help me with this issue ?

Python version: 3.6.6 64bit on Windows 7
Selenium version: 3.141.0
Firefox version: 63.0.1 64bit
Gecko driver: 0.23.0

Comment: you can expand the list to include :  "application/txt,text/plain,text/txt,text/txt"  . Problem solved.

Comment: You can open Dev tools (F12), switch to Network tab and check the exact MIME-type (content-type header) of target file

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for the suggestion, it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion received from Andersson, i checked the MIME type of those and it seems to be different from `text/plain`. So i simply added the new MIME type to `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` and it worked.